# Can't pull kubernetes dns container from behind proxy

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to enable the skyDNS addon for my kubernetes cluster. I'm behind a corporate proxy, and it seems to be unable to talk to gcr.io. The following errors show up in the logs:

```
Oct 20 13:55:46 atomic01.localdomain kubelet[112453]: W1020 13:55:46.143403  112453 manager.go:1569] Failed to pull image "gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.11" from pod "kube-dns-v9-w492r_kube-system" and container "kube2sky": image pull failed for gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.11, this may be because there are no credentials on this request.  details: (invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value)
```

Anything I try to pull from gcr.io fails, even manually:

```
# docker pull gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.9
Trying to pull repository gcr.io/google_containers/etcd ... failed
invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

I've got HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variables configured in `/etc/sysconfig/docker`. As well I have `INSECURE_REGISTRY='--insecure-registry gcr.io'` enabled in the same config file.

I had to apply a workaround of manually pulling the `pause` container from docker.io and specifying it with `--pod_infra_container_image=docker.io/kubernetes/pause:latest`

Is there such a workaround for the DNS containers? I can pull images from other docker registries just fine. What is different with the gcr.io registry and how can I use it with kubernetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What config file are you using to launch the DNS add-on? You should be able to just edit it (or make a copy of [this one](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/dns/skydns-rc.yaml.in)) and point it at a different registry.

Comment: Thanks. That is the file I'm using to launch it. I thought about doing that, but those containers are not on docker hub (or anywhere else that I can find). Well, they are on docker hub, but wildly out-dated. Any suggestions on what I could point it at, or, any suggestions on what's special about gcr.io compared to other registries?

Comment: Right now they are only pushed to gcr.io and we don't have a good release process in place (feel free to comment on https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8686). For now your best bet is to build them yourself and push them to a registry that you can reach.

Comment: Thank you, I had not thought about building them myself, but that seems like a viable option!